# How to use new NET 6 Static assets in Razor class libraries with blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

From the release notes at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-6/ it should be easy to embed static assets from libraries.

I followed the example but this seems not to work for Blazor web assmeblies. The added js asset results in a 404. Anyhting special to do for webassembly or does it just not work ?

Comment: That post is two years old - Blazor has changed a lot since then. Here is the 3.1 version - and you can toggle to .NET 5 on that page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/components/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#create-an-rcl-with-static-assets

Comment: Ah stupdi me ! I was reading the "6" in the article and though it was NET 6 :)